# LDAP Database string connects to default dataabse

Tags: database, ldap, sybase

I ma using ldap connection string to connect to sybase database.In string I am specifying database to which i needs to connect but instead of that its connecting to master database. Can please someone suggest what needs to be changed so it will connect to specified database.

```
<jdbc-driver-params>      
<url>
jdbc:sybase:jndi:ldap://gldap.intra.net:40389/sybaseServername=QLNDS13900,ou=SybaseNames,ou=global,ou=databases,ou=services,dc=intranet,dc=net
</url>
 <driver-name>com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver</driver-name>
 <properties>
            <property>
                <name>database</name>
                <value>p_dbukprog01</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>java.naming.security.principal</name>
                <value>uid=SybaseNames,ou=users,ou=ACL,ou=databases,ou=services,dc=intranet,dc=net</value>
            </property>

            <property>
                <name>java.naming.provider.url</name>
                <value>ldap://gldap.intra.net:40389/ou=SybaseNames,ou=global,ou=databases,ou=services,dc=intranet,dc=net</value>
            </property>
        </properties>

    </jdbc-driver-params>
```

Comment: Assuming this is Sybase ASE ... have you verified your login has access to the desired database (eg, if you login with `isql` and issue `use <dbname>` ... are you placed in <dbname> or do you get an error)?

Comment: i checked we have access

Comment: IS there any way so we can specify database name in LDAP string only

Comment: sorry, I'm not a jdbc/ldap programmer; just wanted to verify this wasn't a permissions issue on the Sybase side.